# Confusion about constant class instance in Swift

Tags: swift

```
let myclassInstance1 = myclass()
let myclassInstance2 = myclassInstance1
myclassInstance1.prop1 = 2
myclassInstance2.prop1 = 3
```

This code is supposed to throw error as I am altering the constant.

But it's not happening.

How come?

Comment: Related: [Why constant constraints the property from a structure instance but not the class instance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38010936/why-constant-constraints-the-property-from-a-structure-instance-but-not-the-clas)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class instance is not constant. Just the reference is.

This means you **cannot** do this:

```
let myClassInstance = MyClass()
myClassInstance = MyClass()
```

Comment: Great ! Answer Sir ! Thanks