# Setting Part of Swift Computed Structure

Tags: swift, data-structures, computed-properties

I was wondering if this behavior in the swift language is documented anywhere.  I haven't been able to find it in the official documentation.  It is best expressed in code:

```
var testBacking = CGPoint(x: 3, y: 5)
var testPoint:CGPoint {
    get {
        print("getter called")
        return testBacking
    } set {
        print("setter called with newValue = \(newValue)")
        testBacking = newValue
    }
}
testPoint.x = 10 //  getter called
                 //  setter called with newValue = (10.0, 5.0)
```

As you can see, I am only setting the `x` component of the computed structure `testPoint`, and in doing so, swift automatically calls the getter first and pulls out the `y` component and builds a complete structure that it then passes to the setter as newValue.  This seems like appropriate behavior.  My question is: Where is this behavior documented?  Have I missed it, or is it simply not mentioned?

Comment: Somewhat related: [Why constant constraints the property from a structure instance but not the class instance?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38010936/2976878)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to understand this is to consider a similar but simpler case without your extra complications. Let's just talk about this:

```
struct S {
    var name = "matt"
}
var s = S()
s.name = "mogelbuster"
```

How does that work? What happens when we set `s.name`? First, pull out the current value of `s`; then, we set its `name` property; then, we set the value of `s` to this new struct. (You can easily confirm that last part by putting a setter observer on `s`.)

Setting a struct's property by way of a reference, then involves getting the reference's value (the struct), setting the property, and setting the reference's value with the new struct. That's because a struct is a *value type*. It cannot be mutated in place, so setting a property by way of a reference to a struct involves setting into the reference.

What you are doing with `testPoint` is merely a computed-variable version of the same process. The mere act of speaking of `testPoint.x` means that we must *get* `testBacking`, to find out what it is. Thus, the getter is called. Then you set into `testPoint.x`, thus calling the setter to write the new value back into `testBacking`.

---

Note that the same thing would *not* be true if we were working with a class. Here's a variation on your original example:

```
    class PointHolder {
        var point = CGPoint(x:3, y:5)
        var x : CGFloat {
            get { return point.x }
            set { point.x = newValue }
        }
    }
    var testBacking = PointHolder()
    var testPoint:PointHolder {
        get {
            print("getter called")
            return testBacking
        } set {
            print("setter called with newValue = \(newValue)")
            testBacking = newValue
        }
    }
    testPoint.x = 10 // getter called, but _not_ setter
```

In the last line, the `testPoint` setter is *not* called — because a class instance is a *reference type* and is mutable in place. `testBacking` is changed without setting, because what we got from `testBacking` when we said `testPoint.x`, and the getter was called, is a reference; a change to this changes the thing `testBacking` points to *without* setting into it.