# Why does a property observer run when a member of the existing value is changed?

Tags: swift, properties, didset, property-observer

Please consider this Swift code. I have a class which wraps an instance of another class. When I set a property on the held value, the wrapper class's property observer is run.

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    var msgStr: String? { get set }
}

class MyClass: MyProtocol {
    var msgStr: String? {
        didSet {
            print("In MyClass didSet")
        }
    }
}

class MyWrapperClass {
    var myValue: MyProtocol! {
        didSet {
            print("In MyWrapperClass didSet")
        }
    }
}

let wrapperObj = MyWrapperClass()
wrapperObj.myValue = MyClass() // Line1
wrapperObj.myValue.msgStr = "Some other string" // Line2
```

The output of above code is:

> In MyWrapperClass didSet
>   In MyClass didSet
>   In MyWrapperClass didSet

I know that `didSet` is called when the value of the variable changes.

So when above code at "Line1" executes I understand that "In MyWrapperClass didSet" is printed, and that is fine.

Next when Line2 executes, I expect "In MyClass didSet" to be printed which correctly happens, but I am not sure why "In MyWrapperClass didSet" is printed, as the property `myValue` is not changed. Can someone explain why?

Comment: Can you show us the code in which you make the actual assignments to these properties?

Comment: @ItaiFerber The last three lines of the code snippet.

Comment: Completely unrelated to your question, but don't use implicitly unwrapped optional properties as an alternative to writing initialiser(s) for your class (in which case the properties can be non-optional).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swift needs to treat the mutation of `myValue.msgStr` as having value semantics; meaning that a property observer on `myValue` needs to be triggered. This is because:

1. `myValue` is a protocol-typed property (which also just happens to be optional). This protocol isn't class-bound, so conforming types could be both value and reference types.
2. The `myStr` property requirement has an implicitly `mutating` setter because of both (1) and the fact that it hasn't been marked `nonmutating`. Therefore the  protocol-typed value *may well* be mutated on mutating though its `myStr` requirement.

Consider that the protocol could have been adopted by a value type:

```
struct S : MyProtocol {
  var msgStr: String?
}
```

In which case a mutation of `msgStr` is semantically equivalent to re-assigning an `S` value with the mutated value of `msgStr` back to `myValue` (see [this Q&A for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38010936/2976878)).

Or a default implementation could have re-assigned to `self`:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
  init()
  var msgStr: String? { get set }
}

extension MyProtocol {
  var msgStr: String? {
    get { return nil }
    set { self = type(of: self).init() }
  }
}

class MyClass : MyProtocol {
  required init() {}
}

class MyWrapperClass {

  // consider writing an initialiser rather than using an IUO as a workaround.
  var myValue: MyProtocol! {
    didSet {
      print("In MyWrapperClass didSet")
    }
  }
}
```

In which case the mutation of `myValue.myStr` re-assigns a *completely new* instance to `myValue`.

If `MyProtocol` had been class-bound:

```
protocol MyProtocol : class {
  var msgStr: String? { get set }
}
```

or if the `msgStr` requirement had specified that the setter must be non-mutating:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
  var msgStr: String? { get nonmutating set }
}
```

then Swift would treat the mutation of `myValue.msgStr` as having reference semantics; that is, a property observer on `myValue` won't get triggered.

This is because Swift knows that the property value cannot change:

1. In the first case, only classes can conform, and property setters on classes cannot mutate `self` (as this is an *immutable reference* to the instance).
2. In the second case, the `msgStr` requirement can only either be satisfied by a property in a class (and such properties don't mutate the reference) or by a computed property in a value type where the setter is non-mutating (and must therefore have reference semantics).

Alternatively, if `myValue` had just been typed as `MyClass!`, you would also get reference semantics because Swift knows you're dealing with a class:

```
class MyClass {
  var msgStr: String? {
    didSet {
      print("In MyClass didSet")
    }
  }
}

class MyWrapperClass {
  var myValue: MyClass! {
    didSet {
      print("In MyWrapperClass didSet")
    }
  }
}

let wrapperObj = MyWrapperClass()
wrapperObj.myValue = MyClass() // Line1
wrapperObj.myValue.msgStr = "Some other string" // Line2

// In MyWrapperClass didSet
// In MyClass didSet
```

Comment: ok, so the idea is - "Whenever a value type is changed, either itself or one of its properties, it is like creating a new copy." And my snippet printed extra "In MyWrapperClass didSet" because (1) The object was of type protocol and (2) the implementor of the protocol could be also of a value type since protocol was not restricted to reference types. Correct?

Comment: @AkshayShah Yes, spot on :) Though strictly it's not just the use of value types, as said in my answer, protocol extensions (of non-class bound protocols) are allowed to re-assign to `self` in mutating contexts (such as a property setter that hasn't been marked `nonmutating`). But once you make the protocol class-bound, this becomes illegal as property setters become non-mutating (to give reference semantics).

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this is happening because your `protocol` is not specified to be a `class` `protocol`.  Because of that, `MyProtocol` could be a `struct` and thus `didSet` is triggered when the object is changed in any way (which is correct behavior for a value type).

If you change your `protocol` to:

```
protocol MyProtocol: class {
    var msgStr: String? { get set }
}
```

then Swift knows that `MyProtocol` represents a reference type, so `didSet` will not be called for `myValue` in `MyWrapperClass` when the string is set.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug, see: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-239

Also workaround is predefining variable, like:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    var msgStr: String? { get set }
}

class MyClass: MyProtocol {
    var msgStr: String? {
        didSet {
            print("In MyClass didSet")
        }
    }
}

class MyWrapperClass {
    var myValue: MyProtocol! {
        didSet {
            print("In MyWrapperClass didSet")
        }
    }
}

let wrapperObj = MyWrapperClass()
wrapperObj.myValue = MyClass() // Line1
var obj = wrapperObj.myValue!
obj.msgStr = "Some other string" // Line2
```

Comment: That bug is just talking about *getting* a value from a property on a protocol-typed value triggering `didSet`, which is definitely wrong. In OP's case however, they're assigning a new value to said property, which should trigger `didSet` because such a mutation *can* (semantically and literally) mutate the protocol-typed value (as the property requirement has an implicitly `mutating` setter).

Comment: Current situation is bug for classes, but not for structs. Value is reassigned by the same value, which is not correct. See a new example inside website with swift bugs.